# Rails: assets unavailable in staging environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, puma

I'm trying to setup a staging environment.

I copied the environments/production.rb to create environments/staging.rb.

I tested the staging environment locally and ran

```
RAILS_ENV=staging rake assets:clean assets:precompile
RAILS_ENV=staging rails s
```

Assets are properly generated in public/assets, and when I load a page, the links to the assets are correct (eg: /assets/application-e014056a81279320a97c71ed25eb46ab.css)

But the browser can't load them and if I try to open

```
http://localhost:3000/assets/application-e014056a81279320a97c71ed25eb46ab.css
```

I get a 404.

Now the strange thing is that it works in production, with:

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:clean assets:precompile
RAILS_ENV=production rails s
```

For both environments/staging.rb and environments/production.rb, the config is

```
config.serve_static_assets = false

config.assets.compile = false

config.assets.digest = true
```

And in application.rb

```
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(assets: %w(development test)))
```

Do you have any idea where to look ? What else could differentiate the staging environment from the production environment ?

Comment: You mentioned the links to the assets are correct - so just to make double sure - the names of the files in the links exactly match the names of the generated files in staging?

Comment: @jefflunt Yes. I just found the solution though! Thanks for reading and trying to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I had forgotten the role of the 'rails_12factor' gem.

I updated my Gemfile to

```
gem 'rails_12factor', group: [:staging, :production]
```

And everything works now.